# I am not able to hide the div tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hello friends I have three div tags on my page..

I am trying to hide two div tags when initial page load

```
<div id="firstpage">

</div>

<div id="secondpage">

</div>
<div id="thirdpage">

</div>
```

my script is

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#secondpage").hide();
  $("#thirdpage").hide();
});
</script>
```

but I am seeing all my div tags is that something I am doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: try closing your divs `</div>`

Comment: sorry it my typo i did that.. I wil update question ..

Comment: If you are including jquery, and you've made all the changes the comments / answers have suggested, it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TH4cS/ Can you post your actual content if you have anything more than this?

Comment: Continue your fix on @leted's answer - not `<script type="text/javascript>` but `<script type="text/javascript">` (closing quote)

Comment: don't see jquery included in your code

Comment: `</asp:Content`... is that also a typo?

Comment: the > is after the code, Hristo

Comment: I've rolled the question back as it was edited so as to not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your enclosing  tags are wrong/missing, could be unrelated though.

EDIT:

1) Install Firebug and check under the Net->JS tab to see whether the jquery is actually loaded.
I bet it isn't. There should be a separate GET request for the .js file.
2) Firebug's `Console` should give you errors for undefined stuff if JQuery isn't included.

Most likely you just don't have JQuery included, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it onload, why not do it in css?

```
#secondpage,
#thirdpage {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: And, like the comments suggest.. close your divs.

Comment: Preumably so they don't get stuck closed for non-JS users.

Comment: @David touche. I've heard of these users.

Answer (score 2):

That script won't execute because the opening  tag isn't closed:

```
<script type="text/javascript?
```

ought to be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not including jQuery. There are a few ways to include jQuery -- http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=609